# How to display data from database with a html table

Tags: php, html, pdo

I'm trying to display the data from my database, inside an HTML table. The main problem is: the table doesn't appear.

```
<html>
<head>
<body>    
<table> 
<tr> 
<th>Id</th>  
<th>String</th>  
<th>Array</th> 
</tr> 

<?php
// Mostrar dados
echo "<table>";
{
$databaseName = 'visteon';

$pdo = new Pdo('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=' . $databaseName, 'root', '');

$result = $pdo->query('SHOW TABLES FROM ' . $databaseName)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

$Tabela = [];
foreach ($result as $r) {
$Tabela[] = $r[0];
}

$data = [];
foreach ($Tabela as $Tabela) {
$data[$Tabela] = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $Tabela)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
echo "</table>";
var_dump($Tabela);
var_dump($data);

}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add `<tr>` then `<td>` to `<table>`.

Comment: Your SQL query code is vulnerable to SQL injection code. You should use Prepared Statement with [prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: @yunzen There is no user input being used, so the code is not open to SQL injection. Also you can't prepare a database or table name

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `try-catch` in your code like this:

```
try {
  $pdo = new Pdo('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=$databaseName .', 'root', 
  array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
  $result = $pdo->query('SHOW TABLES FROM ' . $databaseName)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  throw new Exception("Error with PDO: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

and correct your code (check my 2nd line).

Comment: `PDO` does not throw any exception by default

Comment: What @DarkBee said and also printing just Oh noes is not the way to go. Please check out the PHP error reporting rules, https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting

Answer (score 0):

You're missing complete inner table structure in your code, plus you're not outputing data to the HTML table, just creating local PHP variables and dumping their value after table is generated.